# Has any question on ELU ever won 3 gold badges?

Tags: discussion

Has any question on ELU ever received three gold badges:  10,000 views; 100 upvotes; and 100 favorites?  The question, [Which word begins with "y" and looks like an axe in this picture?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395382/which-word-begins-with-y-and-looks-like-an-axe-in-this-picture), is close, and I am rooting for it.

Comment: Probably this one: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their and this one https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order and this one https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen , while this one is close to getting the third star https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/did-english-ever-have-a-formal-version-of-you

Comment: Also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another

Comment: And this one, which is closed https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools.  And that is IT.

Comment: The interesting thing is though, from a statistics point of view, all five stellar badges were awarded at least three or more years *after* the questions were posted. They accumulated 100 favourites over a much longer span of time than the Y question. So, it's still set to break a new record.

Comment: The Y-question now has three close votes.  Madness!

Comment: @ab2 I believe you mean three **yellow** badges :)

Comment: @DanBron It's not yellow; it's three **yxa** badges. I know a guy who can explain how it's yxa. ***`;P`***

Comment: **99** favourites. Only onee more "favourite" is needed and it's a [**stellar badge**](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/stellar-question). The seventh badge awarded out of 86 thousand questions, quite an achievement. And the question is currently at second position, for the highest upvoted post.

Comment: The most difficult and rarest badge has to be [Reversal](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/reversal). Maybe it's been awarded on StackOverflow, (don't know), but it will never be earned here, that's for sure.

Comment: Posting the link because a reversal badge was awarded but also because the story is really good! Academia has great life stories https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45036/i-was-caught-cheating-in-my-exam-how-should-i-deal-with-it

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Just checked -- 07:20 EDT -- 100 favorite votes.

Comment: Yay!! Stellar question awarded almost one hour ago. :) I have special powers!!

Comment: @Mari-LouA The question beat all sorts of benchmarks, the gold badge hat trick is the cherry on top. What a fun ride.

Comment: I feel like I have to accept Dan Bron's answer, so he can get a brand new [Populist](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/populist) badge, event though his answer does not help me! I'm not going to use _Yxa_ as the Y-word when teaching my son! But the researh was remarkable!

Comment: @gmauch As I read the Populist description, it goes to an answer that was not accepted.

Comment: @ab2 you're right, I misread it. I would have to accept a different answer for Dan Bron to get it. If I accept it, he would get a more ordinary [Guru badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/guru).

Comment: @gmauch Don't accept or not-accept any answers based on badges. Accept the answer that helped you most (that's what "accepting" is supposed to mean), or none if you feel like it. Thank you for your gratitude, but I've been more than repaid by the post's general reception. If it helps you, when the answer's score hit 100, I earned the relatively rare gold "great answer" badge. That said, if you visit the chat room where comments under my Q were moved, you'll see a user found *definitive* evidence the clipart was intended to be Swedish; I need to update my post. But we have the "correct" A.

Comment: @DanBron Your answer seems to be the correct one for the question I posted. You explained the meaning of the the Y on that ball. Now that I know it is Swedish, I have a different question which is: "What can I tell my kid that this **Y**xa means in english?". And I think I'll use **Y**ellow. Not perfect, but recognizable (with a little good-will).

Comment: @gmauch  There are answers for every stage of his life. As a toddler, teach him yellow.  When he is older, and you want to teach him to question the obvious, introduce him to the answers of Draakhond and and PaulP51D.  When he has to write a serious term papers, he should look at Theraot and 1006a.  When he has to write his senior thesis in college, Dan Bron.  He may be utterly sick of the ball by then. :)

Comment: @gmauch Haha, the irony! My arch-enemy, *yellow*.  I agree of the options, it's the most *useful* answer for your application. ;)

Comment: @gmauch Please don't accept the yellow answer.  I think that would disappoint many people.

Comment: @Mari-LouA not once, but **275 times** https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal.  [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124226/etymological-root-and-usage-of-create) is probably the closest at the moment.

Comment: @marcellothearcane if you're interested, there are [111 questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+score%3A..-5) on EL&U with a score of  -5 or higher. Many of these questions are closed, in theory the reversal badge is obtainable, it's there for the taking. UPDATE [33 questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+score%3A..-5+closed%3Ano) are not closed

Comment: @Mari-LouA hah! I only have one answer > 20 upvotes. You're more likely!

Comment: Three [pricks](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/will-you-please-insist-on-explanations-for-down-voting#comment42560_10476) have downvoted this joyous, and celebratory post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of July 5th, 2017, there are seven questions on ELU with three gold badges.  They are:

**1.** [Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun ("his" vs. "her" vs. "their")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their)

266 net upvotes///62,062 views///103 favorites///Aug 2010 date posted

**2.** [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

253///102,462///167///August 2010

**3.** [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen)

226///301,331///122///August 2010

**4.** [Did English ever have a formal version of "you"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/did-english-ever-have-a-formal-version-of-you)

366///103,924///100///January 2011

Note: This question was at 97 or 98 favorites when the OP asked the Meta question on July 3rd.

**5.** [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

132///34,381///152///April 2011  [more favorites than votes]

[What are your favorite English language tools?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools)  [closed]

128///12,081///148///August 2010   [more favorites than votes]

**7.** [Which word begins with "y" and looks like an axe in this picture?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395382/which-word-begins-with-y-and-looks-like-an-axe-in-this-picture)

378///81,189///101///June 23, 2017

As @Mari-Lou A noted:

> The interesting thing is though, from a statistics point of view, all
>   five [six: one more made the list] stellar badges were awarded at
>   least three or more years after the questions were posted. They
>   accumulated 100 favourites over a much longer span of time than the Y
>   question.

Thanks to @Josh, who compiled the list in his comments.

Comment: To split hairs, it's the users who asked the questions that got the badges.